# Oracle collection insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Getting error in Oracle, to use bulk collect not working at the time of insert. Any suggestion how to resolve below issue.
Happy to use any other option

Getting error

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

```
/*
create table locations
(
 id number(5),
 Name varchar(10)
);

Insert into locations values(1,'India');
Insert into locations values(2,'UK');
Insert into locations values(3,'USA');

create table locations_cpy
(
 id number(5)
);
commit;

*/

drop package  DataTypeIssue ;
/ 

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE DataTypeIssue AS

   TYPE T_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
   TYPE array_of_numbers IS table OF NUMBER(5);
  PROCEDURE DataTypeIssue_example(V_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR);
  
END DataTypeIssue;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY DataTypeIssue AS

   
  PROCEDURE DataTypeIssue_example(V_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR) IS
v_LocationIds array_of_numbers;
v_cnt number;
    v_error_code NUMBER;
  BEGIN

select id BULK COLLECT into v_LocationIds from locations bc;


-- works here in select 
open V_CURSOR for 
   select distinct id from locations
   where id  IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(v_LocationIds));

-- insert getting error
/*
 ORA-00902: invalid datatype
*/

   insert into locations_cpy 
   select distinct 1 from locations
   where id  IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(v_LocationIds)); 
      rollback;
  END DataTypeIssue_example; 
    

END DataTypeIssue;
/
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Getting error in Oracle, to use bulk collect not working at the time of insert. Any suggestion how to resolve below issue.
Happy to use any other option available,

Comment: Did you write all that code without trying it even once during the process?!? Take smaller steps, and verify each step before taking the next one.

Comment: I think i see a problem in your insert statement:  You didnt give us much detail, but in an insert statement you need to specify the values.  You have 2 but i'm not sure if you're getting 2 of the right type in your insert sql.  The following examples show various forms of INSERT statement:

INSERT INTO bonus SELECT ename, job, sal, comm FROM emp
   WHERE comm > sal * 0.25;
...
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, job, sal, comm, deptno)
   VALUES (4160, 'STURDEVIN', 'SECURITY GUARD', 2045, NULL, 30);
...
INSERT INTO dept
   VALUES (my_deptno, UPPER(my_dname), 'CHICAGO');

Comment: like:  this is returning a value, and i think you need 2 values:   select distinct 1 from locations
  where id  IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(v_LocationIds)); 
     rollback;

Comment: Like this:  INSERT INTO locations_cpy 
VALUES (select distinct 1 from locations
  where id  IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(v_LocationIds)), 'Missing Second String Value City ');

Comment: wait, even closer to right way like you did it:  insert into locations_cpy 
  select distince id, Name from locations
  where id  IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(v_LocationIds));

Comment: @jarlh, trying to solve the issue from morning. Looks like cannot use table for insert statement

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into locations_cpy 
 select distinct id, Name from locations
 where id  IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(v_LocationIds)); 
 rollback;
 END DataTypeIssue_example;
```

Comment: sorry locations_cpy  has got only column

Comment: ...is it a number? or varchar?

Comment: it is number please